# pymssql sql update statement

Tags: python, sql, sql-update, pymssql

I have the below syntax. The first cursor.execute \ fetchone pulls back the one row that I want to update. But when I try to run the update query, it updates multiple records.

```
cursor.execute("Select * FROM [DisneyConvoIndex] where [ConversationBaseIndex]=%s order by length DESC;", '0101CFE27C560BEB6C1073FBF741997D79EDBD4610AC')

row = cursor.fetchone()

for row in row:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [DisneyConvoIndex] set [toreview] = 'yes'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to update the row after it's returned. You're just dealing with the data at that point, not the object in the DB. You need to limit the rows you're updating with a where clause. So, use something like

cursor.execute(`"UPDATE [DisneyConvoIndex] set [toreview] = 'yes' WHERE [ConversationBaseIndex]=%s", '0101CFE27C560BEB6C1073FBF741997D79EDBD4610AC'`)

Comment: While I've hard coded the value into this statement for testing, I'll need to loop through the entire sql database (I'm grouping by this [ConversationBaseIndex] field, pull back the minimum row and update just that row. I've tried the limit one syntax but can't get that to work.

Comment: @lelarider - The point you seem to be missing is that right now your second query is always going to update all rows because it does not contain a WHERE clause. Even though you've used the same `cursor` object for both queries the second query has nothing to do with the first one. Instead, you'll need to loop through the results of the first query and use the value returned as a parameter for a WHERE clause of your second query as illustrated in this answer.